# export characters in UTF8 with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, encoding, utf-8

I have some script that have commands like

```
echo 'something'
```

then I run the script from shell like this

```
myScript.sh > myfile.txt
```

and there is no problem on linux, everything looks good. But when I sent the file to a windows looks ugly, I have no experience with different encoding, but I think that I need somehow to write the file with utf8 encoding.

How can I make the file looks the same in linux and windows I have .txt extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assumed that you need to write the file in utf-8. I think your file already is utf-8. I think you need to convert the file to ISO8859-1 (or some other [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)).

Most linux distributions today (2011) save every file in utf-8 by default. In windows however, many programs (for example [notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29#Unicode_detection)) still has problems understanding utf-8.

---

More background information:

There are two common problems why a file looks good on linux, but bad on windows:

1. Different [newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems). You can convert a file from unix newlines to windows newlines using the tool [unix2dos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos).
2. Different [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). You can convert a file to different encodings using the tool [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv).